# Convert UTF-8 to UTF-16 in iconv

Tags: unicode

As far as I know, the UTF-8 form of"你好" (means "How are you?" in English) is
`\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd`, and the UTF-16 form  is `u\u4f60\u597d` (or you can write it as `\x4f\x60\x59\x7d`).

Now I use iconv to convert from UTF-8 to UTF-16. At first, I created a new file, with one line("你好") in it, named  test, and I run the command:

```
cat test | iconv  -f  UTF-8 -t UNICODE  
��`O}Y
```

It's not \x4f\x60\x59\x7d. How can I get the right output?

Comment: The prompt doesn't support utf-8?

Comment: Q: Just out of curiousity, what is the language? The character set?  Is '\xe4\xbd\xa0\xe5\xa5\xbd' actually six 1-byte UTF-8 characters?  Or 3 16-bit UTF-16 characters?  How do the six bytes in the 1st string map to the four bytes in the second?  A "conversion" just doesn't make sense.  IMHO... :(

Comment: chinese,in utf-8 ,three bytes is one character.

Comment: Nit: UTF-8 is a specific byte-sequence *representation* of Unicode. *One can no more convert UTF-8 to Unicode than one can convert a Decimal value to an Integer Value.* However, one can convert a Decimal representation of an Integer Value to a Binary representation and thus one can convert a UTF-8 representation of Unicode to *another* representation such as UTF-16 .. or what may be appropriate.

Comment: Looks like byte-order confusion to me, but using UTF-16 instead of 'UNICODE' might work better.

Comment: @Dd Pp - I never knew that - thank you.  Q: did Anon ymous's suggestion, `cat test | iconv -f UCS-2 -t UTF-16`,  help?  Or `dat test | iconv -f UTF-8 -t UTF-16`? See also this link.  It's for AIX (not Linux), but might still be useful: [Using the iconv Command](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.nls/doc/nlsgdrf/iconv.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not `UTF-8`, but `UCS-2`

Try:-

```
cat test | iconv  -f  UCS-2 -t UTF-16
```